# corr.test select only r values with significant p values

Tags: r, list, dataframe

The output of the function corr.test gives a list, where the r element is a double of r-values and the p element is a double of p-values. How can I output an element of r that selects only for the positions of the frame with significant p-values, as indicated in the p element?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this:

```
cor1 <- corr.test(df)
cor1sig <- ifelse(cor1$p < 0.05, cor1$r, NA)
```